# Sql Count on many to many

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

**post**

`id | statement | date`

**features**

`id | feature`

**post_feature** (many to many table between Post and Feature)

`post_id | feature_id`

I want to fire a query that will give me count of different distinct features and its respective features for the posts that are in given date period. I have just started learning SQL and I am not able to crack this one.

I tried the following one but not getting correct results.

```
 SELECT f.feature, count(f.feature)
   FROM  post_feature l 
   JOIN  features f ON (l.featureid = f.id AND l.featureid IN (
   select post.id from post where post.date > 'some_date'))
   GROUP BY f.feature
```

Comment: Can you clarify using an example data ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
       SELECT f.feature, count(f.feature)
       FROM  post_feature l 
       JOIN  features f ON l.featureid = f.id 
       JOIN  post p ON l.post_id =p.id 
       WHERE p.date > 'some_date'
       GROUP BY f.feature
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select f.feature, count(*)
from  post_feature l inner join features f on l.feature_id = f.id
                     inner join post p on l.post_id = p.id
where p.date > 'some_date'
group by f.feature
```

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL is quite creative.  However, your join in the IN clause is on the wrong columns.  It should be on postid to postid.

Although that fixes the query, here is a better way to write it:

```
 SELECT f.feature, count(f.feature)
 FROM  post p join
       post_feature pf
       on p.id = pf.postid join
       feature f
       on pf.featureid = f.id
 where post.date > 'some_date'
 GROUP BY f.feature
```

This joins all the tables, and then summarizes by the information you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   SELECT f.feature, count(DISTINCT f.feature) 
   FROM  post_feature l  
   JOIN  features f ON (l.featureid = f.id AND l.featureid IN ( 
   select post.id from post where post.date > 'some_date')) 
   GROUP BY f.feature
```